# Get base class type in Python

Tags: python

```
class a:
    pass

class b(a):
    pass

c = b()
type(c) == a #returns False
```

Is there an alternative to `type()` that can check if an object inherits from a class?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance): `isinstance(obj, Klass)`

Answer (score 2):

[`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) and [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass) are applicable if you know what to check against. If you don't know, and if you actually want to list the base types, there exist the [special attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes) `__bases__` and `__mro__` to list them:

To list the immediate base classes, consider `class.__bases__`. For example:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path.__bases__
(<class 'pathlib.PurePath'>,)
```

To effectively recursively list all base classes, consider `class.__mro__` or `class.mro()`:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path.__mro__
(<class 'pathlib.Path'>, <class 'pathlib.PurePath'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> Path.mro()
[<class 'pathlib.Path'>, <class 'pathlib.PurePath'>, <class 'object'>]
```

If having an instance of a class, remember to first access its class using `.__class__`.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> class a:
...   pass
... 
>>> class b(a):
...   pass
... 
>>> c = b()
>>> d = a()
>>> type(c) == type(d)
True
```

`type()` returns a type object. a is the actual class, not the type

Comment: Your answer seems to be in contradiction to what the OP says in his question !? I am just beginning to go towards type checking, so I am interested in any comments. Are you sure that type(c) == type(d) ?

Comment: both `type(c)` and `type(d)` return a `class instance` type, so they must be equal. I think we should use `isinstance` here. You can confirm this by creating `class x: pass` and `z=x()`, there's no inheritance between `class x` and `class a`, but you will still find `type(z)==type(c)` returns True.

Comment: The above is for Python 2.7.8. In Python 3.4.1, the `type(c)` and `type(d)` will return `class 'type'`, which will also lead to `True` result. But it doesn't say `c` and `d` are of the same type.

Comment: In Python 3.51 it returns False.